# Javascript conditional to change url on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, url, anchor

I have landing page where you can select the country to change language.
It has a link where you can request a demo. This link is an anchor tag with a mailto url.
I need to change the mailto url based on the language i selected before.
This is my index.html:

```
<div class="c-navigation__language">
      <div class="c-language__trigger" onclick="languageOptions($(this))">
        <i id="languageSelected" class="flag flag-16 flag-ar"></i>AR<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="c-language">
        <a href="#ar" class="c-language__option is-select" title="Argentina" alt="Argentina" data-iso="ar"><i class="flag flag-16 flag-ar"></i> AR</a>
        <a href="/pt#br" class="c-language__option" title="Brasil" alt="Brasil" data-iso="br"><i class="flag flag-16 flag-br"></i> BR</a>
        <a href="/en#us" class="c-language__option" title="E.E.U.U." alt="E.E.U.U." data-iso="us"><i class="flag flag-16 flag-us"></i> US</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-navigation__menu">
      <a href="mailto:default@defaultmail.com" onclick="changeEmailAdress(); return false;" target="_blank" class="cta cta--accent">Solicitar Demo</a>
    </div>
```

So I create a JavaScript function "changeEmailAdress()":

```
function changeEmailAdress(){
var languageSelected = document.getElementById("languageSelected");
  if (languageSelected.value == "AR")
    languageSelected.setAttribute('href',"mailto:ar@mail.com");
  else if(languageSelected.value == "US"){
    languageSelected.setAttribute('href',"mailto:us@mail.com");
  }
}
```

This function does not work, but I am not able to realize why.

The language selected, for example "AR" "US", is also displayed on the url of the website: "www.site.com/es/#AR", so I also thought about getting those character from the website url and make the conditional from there. Is it possible?

Comment: `(languageSelected.textContent == "AR")` - not `value`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeEmailAdress(a){
  document.getElementById("mailto")
  .setAttribute(
    'href', "mailto:"+a.textContent.toLowerCase()+"@mail.com");
};
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="changeEmailAdress(this)">AR</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeEmailAdress(this)">BR</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeEmailAdress(this)">US</a>
<a id="mailto" href="mailto:default@defaultmail.com" target="_blank">Solicitar Demo</a>
```